# Fraction of bilinear forms vs bilinear form of fraction and the formulation of the objective function of Linear Discriminant Analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

Let $A, B \in M(n, \mathbb{R})$ be $n \times n$ symmetric square matrices with real values and suppose $B$ is invertible. We can define three bilinear forms

- $(u,v) \mapsto u^TAv$
- $(u,v) \mapsto u^TBv$
- $(u,v) \mapsto u^T(AB^{-1})v$

What is the relation between the two scalar quantities $\frac{v^TAv}{v^TBv}$ and $v^T(AB^{-1})v$ as $v$ varies in the unit ball $\{v \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||v|| = 1\}$?

The question is related to how the objective function of Linear Discriminant Analysis is formulated. In that case, $A$ is the between-class covariance matrix and $B$ is the within-class covariance matrix. In that context I read that there should be a direct proportionality between the two.

Comment: I don’t think there is any meaningful comparison, as the two quantities have different degrees of homogeneity. You should at least balance the degrees of homogeneity by restricting $v$ to be a unit vector, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Since $A,B$ are covariance matrices and hence positive definite in your case, we could write
$$
\frac{v^TAv}{v^TBv} = \frac{(B^{1/2}v)^TB^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}(B^{1/2}v)}{(B^{1/2}v)^T(B^{1/2}v)} = \frac{w^TB^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}w}{w^Tw},
$$
I suspect this might be helpful

Comment: Yes, @Ben Grossmann thanks this is very useful.

Comment: If $B  \in M(n,\mathbb{R})$ is positive definite and symmetric, it has a unique positive-definite square root $B^{\frac{1}{2}}$. But is such a square root also symmetric?